# Previewing more context when searching PDF using Preview in macOS

Tags: macos, preview.app

When searching (`CMD + F`) a PDF in Preview for macOS, we are shown the searched word(s) in context in the column to the left. This context usually shows 2-3 lines.

Question: Is there a way to show more than that to get more text in context of that matching text passages?

Thanks.